# Program using read() entering into an infinite loop

Tags: c, linux, gcc

```
1oid ReadBinary(char *infile,HXmap* AssetMap)
{
    int fd; 
   size_t bytes_read, bytes_expected = 100000000*sizeof(char); 
   char *data;

   if ((fd = open(infile,O_RDONLY)) < 0) 
      err(EX_NOINPUT, "%s", infile);


   if ((data = malloc(bytes_expected)) == NULL)
      err(EX_OSERR, "data malloc");

   bytes_read = read(fd, data, bytes_expected);

   if (bytes_read != bytes_expected) 
      printf("Read only %d of %d bytes %d\n", \
         bytes_read, bytes_expected,EX_DATAERR);

   /* ... operate on data ... */
    printf("\n");
    int i=0;
    int counter=0;
    char ch=data[0];
    char message[512];
    Message* newMessage;
    while(i!=bytes_read)
    {

        while(ch!='\n')
        {
        message[counter]=ch;
        i++;
        counter++;
        ch =data[i];
        }
    message[counter]='\n';
    message[counter+1]='\0';
//---------------------------------------------------
    newMessage = (Message*)parser(message);
    MessageProcess(newMessage,AssetMap);
//--------------------------------------------------    
    //printf("idNUM %e\n",newMessage->idNum);
    free(newMessage);
    i++;
    counter=0;
    ch =data[i];
    }
   free(data);  

}
```

Here, I have allocated 100MB of data with malloc, and passed a file big enough(not 500MB) size of 926KB about. When I pass small files, it reads and exits like a charm, but when I pass a big enough file, the program executes till some point after which it just hangs. I suspect it either entered an infinite loop, or there is memory leak.

**EDIT** For better understanding I stripped away all unnecessary function calls, and checked what happens, when given a large file as input. I have attached the modified code

```
void ReadBinary(char *infile,HXmap* AssetMap)
{
    int fd; 
   size_t bytes_read, bytes_expected = 500000000*sizeof(char); 
   char *data;

   if ((fd = open(infile,O_RDONLY)) < 0) 
      err(EX_NOINPUT, "%s", infile);


   if ((data = malloc(bytes_expected)) == NULL)
      err(EX_OSERR, "data malloc");

   bytes_read = read(fd, data, bytes_expected);

   if (bytes_read != bytes_expected) 
      printf("Read only %d of %d bytes %d\n", \
         bytes_read, bytes_expected,EX_DATAERR);

   /* ... operate on data ... */
    printf("\n");
    int i=0;
    int counter=0;
    char ch=data[0];
    char message[512];
    while(i<=bytes_read)
    {

        while(ch!='\n')
        {
        message[counter]=ch;
        i++;
        counter++;
        ch =data[i];
        }
    message[counter]='\n';
    message[counter+1]='\0';
    i++;
    printf("idNUM \n");
    counter=0;
    ch =data[i];
    }
   free(data);  

}
```

What looks like is, it prints a whole lot of `idNUM`'s and then *poof* `segmentation fault`

I think this is an interesting behaviour, and to me it looks like there is some problem with memory

**FURTHER EDIT** I changed back the `i!=bytes_read` it gives no segmentation fault. When I check for `i<=bytes_read` it blows past the limits in the innerloop.(courtesy gdb)

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is `1`.  There is no reason to ever write that in your program.

Comment: Yeah, I just kept it for the sake of tomorrow, when I say, I dont want to allocate for a char but for a double.Just saying

Comment: @Carl On the hp48 the sizeof(char) was 2 :-) ...units were 4 bits...

Comment: @ring0 - not if you programmed it in standard C it wasn't.  It's required to be 1 by the language spec.

Comment: The fact that sizeof(char) is always 1 is true but rather misses the point, and there are good reasons to write that, as you noted. However, it's better to use sizeof(value) rather than sizeof(type) ... e.g., sizeof(*data); then you don't have to change it even if the type of the data changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following loop.  Basically, it refactors your implementation so there is only one place where `i` is incremented.  Having two places is what's causing your trouble.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    const char* data = "First line\nSecond line\nThird line";
    unsigned int bytes_read = strlen(data);

    unsigned int i = 0;
    unsigned int counter = 0;
    char message[512];

    while (i < bytes_read)
    {
        message[counter] = data[i];
        ++counter;
        if (data[i] == '\n')
        {
            message[counter] = '\0';
            printf("%s", message);
            counter = 0;
        }
        ++i;
    }

    // If data didn't end with a newline
    if (counter)
    {
        message[counter] = '\0';
        printf("%s\n", message);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Or, you could take the "don't reinvent the wheel" approach and use a standard `strtok` call:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char data[] = "First line\nSecond line\nThird line";
    char* message = strtok(data, "\n");

    while (message)
    {
        printf("%s\n", message);
        message = strtok(NULL, "\n");
    }

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: I am sorry, it gives a segmentation fault.

Comment: I am giving it a look, because imo, it just a refactor.

Comment: @Soham, I ran my code snippets myself and they don't segfault.  Can you post any mods you made to it?

Comment: Karl, I think its giving a segfault somewhere else. I think, its not a problem with your code. (=sheepish grin)

Answer (score 3):

The most glaring problem is this:

```
    while(ch!='\n')
    {
    message[counter]=ch;
    i++;
    counter++;
    ch =data[i];
    }
```

Unless the last character of the file (or the block that you've just read) is `\n`, you'll go past the end of the `data` array, most probably smashing the stack along the way (since you're not checking whether your write to `message` is within bounds).

Comment: but then,how come it worked with other similar but smaller files?

Comment: in fact, if I reduce the data in the files below a certain threshold it works perfectly

Comment: @Soham, probably has to do with your method for generating the large files versus the small ones.  Also, I would change your while loop to be `i < bytes_read`, because you can increment `i` multiple times in the loop that will catch any boundary conditions.

Comment: You should also fix the loop that can go past your 512 sized buffer. If you have a buffer overflow, strange things happen.

Comment: @KARL please check the "FURTHER EDIT" part I have appended. @nos Though I am reading a csv file, but the point you have is a valid one. My problem is I dont have any other way to check the end of line and the beginning of a new one

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that on the system you're using, 500,000,000 is larger than the largest size_t?  If so, bytes_expected may be rolling over to some smaller value.  Then bytes_read is following suit, and you're ending up taking a smaller chunk of data than you actually expect.  The result would be that for large data, the last character of data is unlikely to be a '\n', so you blow right past it in that inner loop and start accessing characters beyond the end of data.  Segfault follows.

Comment: I changed back the `i!=bytes_read` it gives no segmentation fault. When I check for `i<=bytes_read` it blows past the limits in the innerloop.(courtesy gdb)